# Using Apple Frameworks directly with Swift

Tags: swift

Is it possible to use CFNetwork and other frameworks directly with Swift?

(Note: not having to use the Obj-C bridge)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
import CFNetwork
```

It doesn't require any bridging files or Objective-C code on your part, but the Foundation frameworks have not been completely rewritten to use Swift.